# Get current user in MySQL without the hostname

Tags: mysql

I know that we can use the `user()` and `current_user()` function to get the currently logged in user. But I need just the user without the host-name suffixed. I cant seem to find any reference to built-in MySQL function that provides only the username.

Comment: The `user@hostname` _is_ the current user.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX that basically returns the string before a character (in this case '@')

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(current_user(),'@',1)
```

So basically with this you will avoid anything that is not the user part from current_user()

Comment: This is helpful. But is there a built-in MySQL function that does the same. I already have a pretty long query and it can look convoluted.